# Как очистить логи?

Tags: php, хостинг, сервер

Здравствуйте. У меня есть сайт. Как можно узнать кто (с какого IP) загружали файлы на сервер и IP адреса которые эти файлы запрашивали? Можно ли очистить эти логи?

Comment: Раздвоение вопроса какое-то.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы - root, то можно все. Очистка:

`cat /dev/null > /var/log/путь_и_имя_лога`

Если вы имели ввиду, как это сделать средствами php, то в правильно сконфигурированном сервере это вряд ли удастся, т.к. никто в здравом уме httpd, а соответственно и php от root'а не запускает.

Comment: А если попросить хостера поудалять все?

Comment: Хостер вряд ли согласится